# How to allow Sonarr running in Docker access to host volumes

Tags: mount, docker

I've recently installed 18.04 and I have Sonarr, SABnzbd, etc running in Docker. The issue I am having is that my preexisting volume with media is not visible to the new instance of Sonarr, etc.

My media exists on a partition separate from the OS and is mounted to /Storage. When I am searching within Sonarr, I cannot see this path to access existing media files for import. I would assume that SAB/Sonarr cannot see /Storage either for new downloads.

I'm a bit late to the party on Docker... but I have been searching for this answer and bit and hard to find a direct answer.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but it may help someone else looking for an answer. When you configured your YAML you made a volume mapping, the directory /storage will be mapped to something else for that container. You can run portainer and see container volume mappings host-container to see whats the directory was configured as.

The whole idea of a container is that it appears completely separately from the host, with its own network, file directory etc. Therefore you can't directly map a host drive to the container, you have to specify a mapping from the container configuration. I hope this helps you (or someone out there)